# ROS Answers SE migration: Stage + Camera

Tags: ros, simulation, simulator-stage, stage, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to use Stage to simulate a robot with a camera (or a blob-finder) as a sensor. I have added a camera in the world file but I am not able to get camera data published on the /camera/image_raw and other camera sensor topics. With a real-life camera on a robot, I would assume one would have to install the necessary driver for the camera and start it get data published on /camera/image_raw. Do I need to install any camera driver for this arbitrary camera ?  What am I missing here ?

Thanks,
Sagnik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9728/stage-+-camera/) by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 184 on 2011-04-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`stageros` only supports laser and odometry output. If you want support for cameras in ROS, simulated by Stage, you should file an enhancement ticket against the simulator_stage stack.

I'm pretty certain that there is support for simulation a camera in the `simulator_gazebo` stack, but I've never used it.

**Update with responses to Sagnik's further questions:**

The [URDF tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials) are a good place to start, though it is true that getting a robot into Gazebo is a lot more work than getting it into Stage. You'll also have to try to build the Ackermann steering for your model, as there is no simple Ackermann steering controller that I am aware of. See http://answers.ros.org/question/459/how-can-i-simulate-ackermann-steering-in-gazebo and http://answers.ros.org/question/630/linking-joints-in-urdf-andor-gazebo for hints on how to go about doing that.

If you have no need for the full simulation of the robot dynamics, you could always look into how Stage simulates the camera (what format is the image in when it returns it) and add support for outputting simulated cameras to the `stageros` package.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2014-12-04**:
Just in case anyone in the present is checking, stageros does have a camera sensor these days.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its true a lot of the player/stage functionality was taken out.  (Mainly because a lot of it would have been redundant).  However, I too miss the built in blob tracking.  I am not sure exactly what you are doing but you could use a real camera and hold up a certain colored card if you needed the robot to respond a certain way.  (It would be good for testing at least).  I recommend the opencv package included in Ros.

~BM

---

Originally posted by [BlackManta](https://answers.ros.org/users/428/blackmanta/) with karma: 56 on 2011-04-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1